# android:Firebase userproperty value randomly show on console

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am sending firebase custom  userProperty  with updated values.But It randomly shows on Firebase console. I checked with Log events of Firebase .Userproperty values are sending with the events but most of time it does not show on console in debug view  .

```
    mFireBaseAnalytics.setUserProperty("Login_value", "not_login");
```

Is there something I am missing with this?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question/problem here. Are you saying that the user property and its value are not appearing in Firebase or are you saying that values different from what you sent are appearing?

Comment: @faridghar  Sometimes user properties and its value does not appear in firebase. If its first value appear then sometimes changed value of user property does not appear on console or randomly appear. let say, first i sent "not_login" value for user property, "Login_value". If again i send it with "üser_login" then it does not reflect there.